# Multiple Posts by WooCommerce Rest API $woocommerce->post("products", $data);

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have just started working with wordpress, woocommerce and woocommerce rest API.
This is something I am unable to figure out the reason of.

When I use wordpress woocommerce **rest api** to post data, it **posts it multiple time and keeps on posting again and again, like an infinite loop.**

(Get, Delete, Put are working fine)

Code:

```
$product_to_be_duplicated = $woocommerce->get('products/' . $id_to_be_dulpicated);
$duplicated_product = json_decode(json_encode($product_to_be_duplicated), true);
$dup_description = "duplicate of " . $duplicated_product['description'];        
    $dup_tags = array_merge($duplicated_product['tags'], [['id' => $tag_id, 'name' => $tag_name, 'slug' => $tag_slug]]);
    array_shift($duplicated_product);
    $duplicated_product['description']= $dup_description;
    $duplicated_product['tags'] = $dup_tags;
    $duplicated_product['catalog_visibility'] =  'hidden';
    try
    {
        $woocommerce->post('products', $duplicated_product);//the problem statement
    }
    catch (HttpClientException $e) 
    {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
        exit();
    }
```

The only problem is with the post as it is being called and filling database again and again.

Answer (score 0):

How is this piece of code hooked in? Which action is it attached to? Often times, things like this will happen when the code you've hooked to is fired by the code you run, i.e. you've hooked to:

`add_action('save_post', 'my_example_function');`

and your code triggers:

`do_action('save_post');`

In your example, since you're duplicating a product, saving that will trigger the `save_post` action, which calls your code again, which starts your infinite loop.

Read up on this section from the WP docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops

Comment: just calling Woocommerce Api from a cron script outside wordpress